# Laravel 4, How to merge two config files?

Tags: arrays, laravel, merge, config

I have two custom config files in my `app/config` directory where the file names are `admin.php` & `site.php`. Now, I want merge both config files, How can I do it?

In `yii` framework it's possible using something like `CMap::mergeArray(arr1,arr2)`. Is there anythimg available in `Laravel` like that ?

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, just read the files

```
$admin = Config::get('admin');
$site = Config::get('site');
$allConfig = array_merge($admin, $site);
```

Now in `$allConfig` variable, you'll get the merged configurations of both files.